Looking for a Video Lecture on Conley's Decomposition Theorem
I am looking for a video lecture that specifically explains Conley's Decomposition Theorem (also known as Conley's Fundamental Theorem of Dynamical Systems), ideally including a detailed discussion and proof.
Most of the materials I find online delve into Conley index theory or focus on broader topics in dynamical systems, but I need something that focuses solely on the decomposition theorem itself.
Does anyone know of a video lecture or any online resource that covers this? I’d really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. Thank you!
